# Python Pandas: ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Relatively new to Pandas and running into the above mentioned error. The following pseudo code describes what I am trying to obtain when merging two DataFrames.

In rows of DataFrame DF, where DF bedrooms are equal to 1, the DataFrame DF 'Multiplier' equals the DataFrame rent_1 'Multiplier'

This is the code I have thus far:

```
#DataFrame DF:
df = pd.DataFrame([
['123 HorseShoe Dr', 'St Petersburg', 2],
['13 Circle Ct', 'Gulfport', 1],
['21 Barcelona Ave', 'Tarpon Springs', 1],
['2113 Marks Dr', 'Treasure Island', 1],

    ], columns=['Address', 'City', 'BedroomsTotal'])
df.fillna(0, inplace=True)

#DataFrame Rent_1
rent_1 = pd.DataFrame([
    ['TREASURE ISLAND', 17.4947],
    ['TARPON SPRINGS', 20.0018],
    ['TIERRA VERDE', 18.3793],
    ['SOUTH PASADENA', 18.4124]    
    ], columns=['City', 'Multiplier'])

rent_1.fillna(0, inplace=True)
.set_index('City')
df.set_index('City')
joined = df.join(rent_1)
print(joined)

#Below is the code that is giving me an issue:
#df.loc['Multiplier'] = np.where(df['BedroomsTotal'] == 1), rent_1['Multiplier'])
np.where(df.loc[df['BedroomsTotal'] == 1], df['Multiplier'], rent_1['Multiplier'])
```

Here is the Traceback:

```
line 1856, in _setitem_with_indexer_missing
    raise ValueError("cannot set a row with mismatched columns")
ValueError: cannot set a row with mismatched columns
```

Any help on this is GREATLY appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is your other condition for `np.where`? You error is happening because your trying to set a series with a tuple

Comment: Perhaps `np.where` is not the best choice of function to execute what I am looking for. The two DataFrames merge on the `['City']` column.

Comment: can you post an expected output. Also please put code for creating df

Comment: DF DataFrame is imported from an excel document similar to the screenshot above. The expected output is mentioned in my above mentioned pseudo code. It can be seen that the `['Multiplier']` column inherits the value 17.4947 which is correct. Technically, all of the lines are running as they should but I am now trying them against the condition of how many bedrooms they have.

Comment: Note that the line that you say gives the error has `rent_1['Multiplier']` as the true return value - this is a `series` and not a scalar value.

Comment: Please include **text** representation of *df* (not a picture). Probably it should include also *City* column, which you failed to include in your screenshot. Another remark is that the result of *rent_1.fillna(0, inplace=True)* is *None*, so you can not chain it with *set_index(...)*. An attempt to run such code results in an error. Even pseudocode should be "error-free".

Comment: Rewriting that line to scalar: `df.loc['Multiplier'] = df.loc[df['BedroomsTotal'] == 1, rent_1['Multiplier']]` returns a Traceback error: `KeyError: "None of [Float64Index([  2.819,  1.5515,...18.4124],\n             dtype='float64')] are in the [columns]"`

Comment: Rewriting as the same line? Could you be more specific? Example: Changed "a" to "b"
Please refer to `numpy.where()` documentation here - https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html

Comment: @skuzzy taking into account your provided numpy documentation. The line should appear as such: `np.where(df.loc[df['BedroomsTotal'] == 1], df['Multiplier'], rent_1['Multiplier'])` however it is now throwing the error: `TypeError: first argument must be an iterable of pandas objects, you passed an object of type "DataFrame"`